# check consecutive letters

Tags: random

I have to generate 200 random letters (function has to do it) separated by commas. It doesn't matter if they are repeated but it must not be consecutively. If they are consecutive, I have to replace it with a new letter generated randomly by my function. I am new to programming. I also cannot modify my function as a constraint.

For the sake of the output, I am generating 10 numbers instead of 200.

This is my working code. I just can't manage to add a new random letter where I deleted a duplicate.

Comment: Random numbers or random letters?

Comment: Your code is for making unique letters. You said that wasn't a requirement, so why are you doing that? Meanwhile, you don't have any code that compares consecutive letters.

Comment: @Barmar Its for random letters. And I think I got my code mixed up since, I can't get it  to compare consecutive letters. Thank you for your help, English is not my first language!

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the chance of consecutive letters, I removed most of the letters from the const of characters.

```js
const characters = 'abcdef';

function getRandomLetter() { return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)).toUpperCase(); }

var randomLetters = [];

for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
randomLetters [j] = getRandomLetter();
while(randomLetters [j] == randomLetters [j-1]){
console.log("consecutive");
randomLetters [j] = getRandomLetter();
}
}

document.write("10 random letters: ", randomLetters );


let uniqueArr = [];

for(let i of randomLetters) {
    if(uniqueArr.indexOf(i) === -1) {
        uniqueArr.push(i);
    }
}
document.write("10 random letters without duplicates: ", uniqueArr);
```

Comment: I think I misexplained . I need it to generate letters A-Z and my original function cannot be modified since its the code given. I need to replace consecutive letters by generating a new letter at the same position. If  Z, A, B, D, G, G, H, A, O, I was generated, it needs to output something like Z, A, B, D, G, *new random letter*, H, A, O

Comment: But thank you so much for helping by theway!

Comment: @dev4chae I updated the answer. what about now?

Answer (score 0):

So if it can not be the same as the previous write your random code to keep generating until it does not match

```js
const characters = Array.from('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

function getRandomLetter(last) {
  const val = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)].toUpperCase();
  if (last === val) return getRandomLetter(last);
  return val;
}

var randomLetters = [];

for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  randomLetters[j] = getRandomLetter(randomLetters[j - 1]);
}

console.log(randomLetters.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator function:

```js
function* randomChars(n) {
  let lastChar, c
  while(n>0) {
    do {
      c = String.fromCharCode((Math.random()*26|0)+65)
    } while (c===lastChar)
    yield (n--, lastChar=c)
  }
}

console.log([...randomChars(200)].join())
```